# War Carded Game Python

Tags: python

I'm creating a Python card game, however, I am having difficulty on how to pull out the values out of the dictionary. I'm importing a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Card, Type, Value
2, Spades, 2
3, Spades, 3
```

I have written the following code:

```
import random, csv ,collections
reader = csv.DictReader(open('deck.csv','r'))
deckcards=[]
for line in reader:
    deckcards.append(line)
random.shuffle(deckcards)
hand1=[]
hand2=[]
player1=[]
player2=[]
while len(deckcards) !=0:
    if len(deckcards) ==0:
        break
    player1.append(deckcards.pop())
    player2.append(deckcards.pop())
def declarewar(hand1,hand2,player1,player2):

    hand1.append(player1.pop())
    hand2.append(player2.pop())
    return hand1,hand2,player1,player2
print statement looks like this:

[OrderedDict([('Card', 'King '), ('Type ', 'Hearts'), ('value', '13')])]
```

Comment: What do you mean you're stuck pulling the values out of the dictionary?  Where exactly is the problem, and what are you trying to do that does not work?

Comment: Well I'm trying to get the value of hand1. When hand1 is printed it looks like this [OrderedDict([('Card', 'King '), ('Type ', 'Hearts'), ('value', '13')])] . So I want to take the value of value which is 13.

Comment: or lets say I want to know what Card it is which is king, how do I pull that value out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hand=[('Card', 'King '), ('Type ', 'Hearts'), ('value', '13')]

#get value from hand
card=hand[0][1] #print result: "King"
type=hand[1][1] #print result: "Hearts"
value=hand[2][1] #print result: "13"

player1=[
[('Card', 'King '), ('Type ', 'Hearts'), ('value', '13')],
[('Card', 'Queen '), ('Type ', 'Diamonds'), ('value', '12')],
[('Card', 'Ace '), ('Type ', 'Hearts'), ('value', '14')]
]

#get player values
for i in range(len(player1)):
    for j in range(3):
        print(player1[i][j][0]+" "+str(i)+": "+player1[i][j][1])
```

Player print result

```
Card 0: King
Type  0: Hearts
value 0: 13
Card 1: Queen
Type  1: Diamonds
value 1: 12
Card 2: Ace
Type  2: Hearts
value 2: 14
```

Comment: I wasn't what i was looking for but thanks it helped.

Comment: Sure thing glad it helped. :)